# Why lseek with offset `-2` and not `-1` to read in reverse?

Tags: c, linux, posix, system-calls, lseek

Why is it `-2` and not `-1`? This is a part of a code that has to write a string from a file to another in reverse. Can you help me understand why it is `-2` and not `-1`?

```
  while ( n >= 0)  {
       read(fdin, &c, 1);
       write(fdout, &c, 1);
       n=lseek(fdin,-2,SEEK_CUR);
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

The `read` part is the one that reverses the characters. Since each `read` of 1 character moves the file position forward by one character, we must go backward *2* characters to advance backwards.

Suppose the file is only 2 characters long, having contents `AB`:

```
AB
```

In the beginning in a part of the code you didn't show here, the file pointer is positioned one before the end of file, so it is pointing at `B`.

```
 |
 v
AB
```

Now we read one character - `B` is read. The file pointer on `fdin` is advanced to the *end of file*.

```
  |
  v
AB
```

If we seek backwards by *one* character, we'll end up at `B` again. But if we seek backwards *2* character, it will point to `A`:

```
|
v
AB
```

And we end up reading first `B` then `A`.

Finally when we try to seek beyond the beginning of the file, `lseek` will return `(off_t)-1` to signify an error condition and the `while` loop condition becomes false and the loop is exited.